# How to send message to event hub via python

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am trying to connect lots of iot objects to an eventhub and save them to a blob storage(also an sql database). I want to do this with python(and I am not sure if this is a recommended practice). The documentation about python was confusing. I tried a few examples but they create an entry to blob storage but entries seems to be irrelevant.

Things like this:
Objavro.codecnullavro.schema\EC{"type":"record","name":"EventData","namespace":"Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging","fields":[{"name":"SequenceNumber","type":"long"}...

which is not what I send. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the azure-eventhub Python SDK to send messages to Event Hub which is available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/).

And there is a [send sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/sync_samples/send.py) showing how to send messages:

```py
import os
from azure.eventhub import EventHubProducerClient, EventData
producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(
    conn_str=CONNECTION_STR,
    eventhub_name=EVENTHUB_NAME
)
with producer:
    event_data_batch = producer.create_batch()
    event_data_batch.add(EventData('Single message'))
    producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)
```

I'm interested in `The documentation about python was confusing. I tried a few examples but they create an entry to blob storage but entries seems to be irrelevant.`

Could you share your code with me? I'm wondering what's the input/output for Event Hub and Storage Blob and how's the data processing flow.

btw, for Azure Storage Blob Python SDK usage, you could check the [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob) and [blob samples] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This is the connection string format for inserting new messages in eventhub using kafka-python. If you were using kafka and want to replace you just have to change this connection string.

```
import ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.options &= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
context.options &= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1

self.kafka = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_HOST,connections_max_idle_ms=5400000,security_protocol='SASL_SSL',value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'),sasl_mechanism='PLAIN',sasl_plain_username='$ConnectionString',sasl_plain_password={YOUR_KAFKA_ENDPOINT},api_version = (0,10),retries=5,ssl_context = context)
```

KAFKA_HOST = "{your_eventhub}.servicebus.windows.net:9093"
KAFKA_ENDPOINT="Endpoint=sb://{your_eventhub}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootSendAccessKey;SharedAccessKey={youraccesskey}"

You can find KAFKA_HOST and KAFKA_ENDPOING from your Azure Console.

Comment: Is there a sample for `self.kafka.send(topic, key= b'my_key', value=s, partition= 0)` ?   It's weird that I got error "KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs"

Comment: I would suggest you to use their native event hub code because you can not use kafka code to pull the events and it's not work properly. Currently I do not have the code for this. Check for the network connectivity and throughput limits as these are major blockers.